# Version 32-bit or 64-bit? How to Check

Tags: java

I tried to find a way how to check if person have 32-bit version or 64-bit version. I need that to make code to do something if there is 32-bit and code which will do something when you have 64-bit.

Answer (score -1):

**check this code**

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Comment: `System.getProperty("os.arch")` returns information about the os, not the vm/jre. You can still run a 32-bit JRE on a 64-bit OS. Try `sun.arch.data.model` which is Oracle VM specific or `java.vm.name` which should end in `32` or `64`.